# Use different SMO version in the same VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net, smo

The SMO-libraries are for a specific version of SQL Server.

So , is there any possibility to use different SMO libraries , in the same VB.net application in order  that my application works regardless of SQL server version?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use older version of SMO-libraries for both servers. I used SMO-libraries from SQL Server 2008R2 in C# apllication and powershell script to migrate DB from 2008R2 to SQL Server 2005. Thus, there shan't be problems and when using VB.net.

Comment: No , it's not true for me. If I use SMO that are for SQL Server 2008R2  , to work with  sql server 2012 or sql server 2005 , I get errors. Doesn't work.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008R2 installed on my desktop. With it's SMO libraries I can connect to another 2008R2 server and to 2005 server. And there no any troubles with it. Please, post the errors which server returns.

Comment: I think it depends what you are using from SMO. Anyway did you try to connect to 2012 version ?

Comment: I used SMO for migration of a database: rename or drop some tables; drop primary keys, foreign key, indexes; drop stored procedures and functions; copy DB structure (with table-data) from 2008r2 to 2005. No, i haven't 2012 version. Try to use SMO version 2012 to connect to 2008r2 and post server errors.